# Appropriate test for detecting a signal in normally distributed noise

Tags: normal-distribution, normality-assumption, histogram

I am doing some signal processing and I have a histogram which has a bell shape when there is only noise in the signal. (I have been advised that this is to be expected due to the central limit theorem)

[image: Histogram]

However when the signal that I am looking for is present

The shape of the histogram changes to 
[image: With Signal]

Note that I have removed the bars in the middle because they are so high it makes it hard to see the detail at the base of the curve.

I would like a test to discriminate between these two cases.

I am aware that there are some [tests for normality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normality_test)  however I am unsure of how appropriate they are in this case as explained [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/2492/is-normality-testing-essentially-useless/2501#2501).

One approach that I have considered is testing the smoothness

> $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{[f''(x)]^2 dx}$

where f is the normal distribution

**EDIT**

As Glen_b sugested, I tried the Anderson Darling Test

```
float[] sortedYs;
sortedYs = Hist.OrderBy(a => a).ToArray<float>();
float[] cdf = new float[sortedYs.Length];

MathNet.Numerics.Distributions.LaplaceDistribution ld = new MathNet.Numerics.Distributions.LaplaceDistribution(U, (b));
for (int i = 0; i < sortedYs.Length; i++)
{
    cdf[i] = (float) ld.CumulativeDistribution(sortedYs[i]);
}

float AD = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < cdf.Length; i++)
{
    AD -= (float)((2 * (i + 1) - 1) * (Math.Log(cdf[i]) + Math.Log(1 - cdf[cdf.Length - 1 - i])));
}
AD /= cdf.Length;
AD -= cdf.Length;
AD *= (float)(1 + (0.75 + 2.25 / cdf.Length) / cdf.Length);
```

(I'm using C# and Math.Net)
I'm still not quite sure if this is how anderson darling works. (about 8000 - 14000 for bubbly, about 4000- 12000 for non bubbly).
Its also probably worth noting that I have quite a large data set, since my images have 1920*1080 pixels.

The AD value calculated is much higher for moving video frames.

The smoothnes calculation is done by estimating 
$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{[f''(x)]^2 dx}$

using the raw data for f
and then by doing the same estimate but using a laplace distribution (using sample mean and b) for f

I find the difference of these two estimates.

I am getting about 0.01 and less for no motion, and higher for moving images. However there is overlap in these categories as well so its not as reliable as I would like yet.

**EDIT**

I'm going to post some more histograms

No Motion
[image: no motion]

Motion Present 
[image: motion]

I was looking at the noise in the tails all this time, but if I step back and look at the whole histogram, it can be seen that images with motion have a conspicuously lower variance in their histogram than images without motion.

I think this might be partially due to the way pixels are categorised into bins in a histogram. (I'm using opencv and emgu so I will have to look at the source code for more clues here). Images with motion actually have a wider spread of gray scale values than images with no motion. However when calculating the histogram, the pixels have to be placed in bins from 0 to 255. So an image with widely varying grayscale values has lower resolution bins. And so, more pixels get placed in the same bin, even if they a bit different. This does kind of ruin my data, but at the same time, its an effect that I can take advantage of too.

Comment: That first diagram plainly isn't showing something normally distributed. It looks more like it's approximately Laplace (double exponential). At a reasonable sample size any decent test for normality would reject your base case.

Comment: Thats very interesting. The graph is actually the frequency histogram of an image, I have performed some background subtraction so that when something in the video moves I get the second histogram. When there is no movement, I get a more or less blank image with some noise which results in the fist histogram.

Comment: Might you consider a two-sample Anderson-Darling like statistic (rather than Kolmogorov-Smirnov, because it puts more emphasis on the tail, where your interest seems to lie) -- that is, to look at the difference in distribution between a blank image and the other image without specifying the distribution of either?

Comment: I should probably also mention that as the video plays, the mean and variance of the histogram seems to vary.

Comment: You appear to have carried out two one-sample A-D tests. If that's what you did, that wasn't my suggestion.

Comment: If you have a distribution that changes over time, you have take account of that if you want to use data across different times.

Comment: I hope this is the correct paper to be looking at http://www.cithep.caltech.edu/~fcp/statistics/hypothesisTest/PoissonConsistency/ScholzStephens1987.pdf

Comment: I should also add that part of the process of creating the histogram involves converting an image of double to an image of byte.

Comment: I've described the binning aspect of the problem here 
http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/99777/calculating-the-variance-of-the-histogram-of-a-grayscale-image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem I had to solve here was choosing the appropriate bin size.

I found [this paper](http://biocurious.com/files/histo-bin-size-scott.pdf) by David Scott which gave me a useful formula.

$h = 3.49 s n^{-1/3}$

where `s` is standard deviation and `n` is the number of samples.

This one worked quite well for me and was derived assuming normally distributed data. I also tried deriving an equation based on a Laplace distribution but the results were not as good in my case.

Answer (score 0):

#### Use the `spectrum.test` function in the `ts.extend` package

Your question does not specify how you got this transformation of your signal, and I have little to say about it in the absence of further information.  In any case, it is possible to test for a signal in noise (without assuming that the noise is normally distributed) using a "permutation-spectrum test".  This is an extension of Fisher's test for detecting a signal in white noise.  The test operates on the time-series rather than the transformation you have given, and it is quite simple to implement.

The test is implemented in the [`spectrum.test`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/ts.extend/versions/0.1.1/topics/spectrum.test) function in the [`ts.extend`](https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=ts.extend) package in `R`.  Here is an example where we generate data with a periodic signal and then test for the presence of the signal.  The test output and resulting plot easily detects the signal.

```
#Load the package
library(ts.extend)

#Generate mock data
set.seed(1)
m      <- 100
SIGNAL <- 0.8*sin(0.3*(1:m))
NOISE  <- rnorm(m)
SERIES <- SIGNAL + NOISE

#Conduct permutation-spectrum test
TEST <- spectrum.test(SERIES)
TEST
        Permutation-Spectrum Test

data:  real time-series vector SERIES with 100 values
maximum scaled intensity = 3.6428, p-value = 0.000208
alternative hypothesis: distribution of time-series vector is not exchangeable 
(at least one periodic signal is present)

#Plot the test results
plot(TEST)
```

[image]